# How to jump to a node using conditions after entities are captured using slots in another node using watson conversation?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am trying to make a Watson conversation that will recommend the right product URL of a retail website.

So when I catch two entities ( item & brand ) in the dialogue node ( using slots ) which recognizes the #shop intent, I want to jump to different nodes depending on the values of those two intents. For example

If the item is a mobile phone and brand is samsung, then I want to jump to a node that will further collect details like color & memory ( using slots ) and provide the user with a custom URL for each combination. i.e url1 for white color and 64 GB phone, url2 for black color & 128 GB phone and so on.

But suppose if the item is a laptop and brand is samsung, then I want to jump to another node that will further collect details like amount of RAM, Hard disk space, processor type etc and provide the user with a custom URL for each combination.

Is this possible?

Also is it possible to skip the user input and move on to processing child nodes without using the "JUMP" option? after collecting values using slots? How is it done?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty broad and the answer is that it can be done.

Each dialog node can react to one or more conditions. Try to design your dialog in a real tree, so that you can branch out to laptops or mobile phone processing, etc. You can use the [**skip user input**](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-overview.html#jump-to) feature to directly go to a child node. That would allows going to a child node directly. Also see the "Configuring the Jump to action" at the same link on how to set up the branching.